# PCA with prcomp gives unexpected results

Tags: r, pca

I'm trying to understand what prcomp does in R, as it uses SVD under the hood.  Here's a simple example using a unit matrix:

```
xdim <- 4
arr <- array(0, dim=c(xdim,xdim))
for(v in 1:xdim) { arr[v,v]=1.0 }
pcaa <- prcomp(arr)
```

pcaa$rotation should contain a unit matrix but doesn't.  If I use

```
pcaa <- prcomp(arr, center=FALSE)
```

then it does.  Shouldn't the eigenvectors be simple to calculate?  Why does centering the data throw it off?

Comment: Not completely sure, but check the variance-covariance matrix (`var(diag(4))`), which is quite different from the raw matrix `diag(4)`.  In particular, there is non-zero (negative) covariance between the elements; intuitively, values that are 1 in one row are 0 for other rows -> negative correlation.  Haven't worked this out analytically (yet), but the covariances for a 4x4 are -1/12 and by numerical experimentation are -1/(n*(n-1)) ...